# Hibernate not working with postgres database

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I'm trying to write a simple program that searches postgres database for specific books. I'm using Hibernate version 5 but getting few errors while running the program. I've attached the screenshots of the error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem was! I did not add the postgres jar into my project folder under reference library. Since I'm using postgres, following is the link for postgres jar download:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/